# Trouble installing libpng in R error: Cannot find such file

Tags: r, linux, directory, conda, libpng

I currently have a conda environment created as "r_env" and is trying to install the "tensorflow" package into R on terminal. However, in R I keep having the same error, regardless if I am install "tensorflow" or "png" package directly from terminal after loading R.

[image]

I currently have the following packages installed in the conda env:

[image]

[image]

It appears to me that the installer is trying to look for the library files in ./conda/envs/r_env/lib/R/library whilst it is already installed in ./conda/envs/r_env. How may I rectify this issue? (Note: I do not have sudo privileges, but any solutions at this point is helpful!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to install `tensorFlow`:

```
library(keras)
  install_keras()
  devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
  install_tensorflow(package_url = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/b8/d6/af3d52dd52150ec4a6ceb7788bfeb2f62ecb6aa2d1172211c4db39b349a2/tensorflow-1.3.0rc0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=1cf77a2360ae2e38dd3578618eacc03b")
  library(tensorflow)
```

After that try installing `png`:

```
install.packages("png")
  library(png)
```

Finally check png:

```
  capabilities()["png"]
```

Output:

```
 png 
TRUE
```

Comment: Hi! I've tried installing keras with my R-terminal, and I've the same error as shown above. 

`
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/home/users/ntu/ling0086/.conda/envs/r_env/lib/R/library/png/libs/png.so':
  libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`
Any idea why this might be so? Is it perhaps something related to the path directory/permissions?